# The cutom filter block disappears when new search key is entered

Tags: 8, blocks

I am using the Search API, I have created a /search page for observing the search results based on three entity types. I have two exposed filter: The "Fulltext Search" filter is located in the navigation bar, and "Filter by content type" is located in the content region. (To split two exposed filters into two different blocks, I had to dublicate a /search page). 
The issue for me is that, whenever the user enters a new search "key", the "Filter by content type" disappears. The "Clear Cache" solves the problem, but in the build() function, I set the max-age to 0, so the reason is not a cache. Why does it happen?

```
public function build(){

if($this->search_filters){
  $render = '';
  foreach($this->search_filters['value'] as $key => $value){
      $block = $this->renderFilter($value, $identifier);
      $render .= render($block);
  }
  return array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => $render,
    '#cache' => array(
      'max-age' => 0
    ),
  );
}
```

}

Comment: Is the behaviour the same for anonymous and authenticated users, or just anonymous?

Comment: I have just tested, for anonymous user the "Filter by content type" disappears immediately, for authenticated user the filter disappears for the second search.

Comment: It always happens with some new serach key, the filter is not affected by some search keys, which I have already used for testing

Comment: It’s definitely caching then